# how to lock table in DB2 without waiting

Tags: db2, locking, wait, db2-luw

I want to lock a table in DB2 (version 11) and I don't want other people wait for my locking when try to update the locked table.
(Thrown an exception or return an error code)

I used the following command:
LOCK TABLE MYTABLE IN EXCLUSIVE MODE

But other connections always wait.

So is there any way to stop waiting?

Comment: Is it Db2 v11 on Linux/Unix/Windows   or  on Z/OS mainframe ?

Comment: @mao: it's on Linux

Comment: You can control your activities but other applications can control their own. They have to set their own lock timeout periods. If you don't want them to wait on an object then the object would have to stop existing as they know it - if RENAME is an option for you that could be the better route. You could also look at the applications using views or aliases to the table that you'd drop when doing this operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Db2 on Linux/Unix/Windows, If you use 'LOCK TABLE ... IN EXCLUSIVE MODE' then other connections will wait for you to commit/rollback.

For Db2 on Linux/Unix/Windows, by default the other connections will wait for either [LOCKTIMEOUT](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/r0000329.html) seconds (default = -1 = wait forever ), or whatever the other application has configured in its connection either via `SET CURRENT LOCK TIMEOUT` (which can include setting NOT WAIT or other values) or in the other application's Db2-client configuration.  See documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0011874.html).

For client side configuration options (db2cli.ini, db2dsdriver.cfg, connection-attributes etc) refer to the Db2 Knowledge center for details.

It's important to understand that either it is the *other* applications that need to adjust their lock timeout (either in their code or in the Db2-client configuration) , or else the database parameter LOCKTIMEOUT will determine their waiting duration.

So , in short, if you want *other* applications to not wait then those applications have to be programmed/configured for that purpose, or the database configuration LOCKTIMEOUT has to be configured appropriately or both of those.

In practice this means you need to either avoid locking tables in exclusive mode (implicitly or explitly), or you need to perform this at the most quiet time and keep the duration of the lock as short as possible. In particular, your job cannot tell the other Db2-connections how to adjust their lockwait behaviour!

Comment: sorry for my poor experience.
The command SET CURRENT LOCK TIMEOUT must be executed after or before running LOCK TABLE command?
I tried as bellow
db2 +c  LOCK TABLE MYTABLE IN EXCLUSIVE MODE
db2 SET CURRENT LOCK TIMEOUT NOT WAIT

And other connections not wait but finish successully

Answer (score -1):

Maybe the other users could use Uncommitted Reads `WITH UR`?

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059225.html

Alternatively, maybe you could use `IN SHARE MODE` instead of an `EXCLUSIVE` lock

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000972.html